# How to create key-value pair property in web user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties, webforms, web-user-controls

I want to pass list of values to web user control from page.

Something like this:

```
<uc:MyUserControl runat="server" id="MyUserControl">
    <DicProperty>
        <key="1" value="one">
        <key="2" value="two">
               ...
    </DicProperty>  
</uc:MyUserControl>
```

How to create some kind of key-value pair property (dictionary, hashtable) in web user control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found one kind of solution:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> labels = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public LabelParam Param
    {
        private get { return null; }
        set
        { 
            labels.Add(value.Key, value.Value); 
        }
    }

    public class LabelParam : WebControl
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public LabelParam() { }
        public LabelParam(string key, string value) { Key = key; Value = value; }
    }
}
```

And on the page:

```
<%@ Register src="MyUserControl.ascx" tagname="MyUserControl" tagprefix="test" %>

<test:MyUserControl ID="MyUserControl1" runat="server">
    <Param Key="d1" value="ddd1" />
    <Param Key="d2" value="ddd2" />
    <Param Key="d3" value="ddd3" />
</test:MyUserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a public `Dictionary` property in the code behind of your user control:

`public Dictionary<int, string> NameValuePair { get; set; }`

Then in the code-behind of the form where you create the new user control, you can populate that new property:

```
Dictionary<int, string> newDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();

newDictionary.Add(1, "one");
newDictionary.Add(2, "two");
newDictionary.Add(3, "three");

MyUserControl.NameValuePair = newDictionary;
```

Comment: In my case, I am not able to access or change the code behind so I must do it from the front side like in my example. Thank you.

Comment: Ah.  In that case you can simply use the server tags right below your control to set the values:
`<uc:MyUserControl runat="server" id="MyUserControl"></uc:MyUserControl>
<% Dictionary<int, string> newDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();

   newDictionary.Add(1, "one");
    ...
   MyUserControl.NameValuePair = newDictionary; %>`  Make sure to add `<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Specialized" %>` at the top of your page for the Dictionary collection.  The same can be done for creating the public property on your control.  Just use server tags.

Comment: Thank you. This will work but not in my case. I need values of the dictionary in user control load event which is not case in your example where I have values in render event (it is to late for me).
I have posted my solution, it is best i could in this moment. And it is working :)

Comment: Excellent.  I'm glad you figured it out.